# Set value using signal is not behaving as expected in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread, qwebview

I have a class in the main thread which initiates another thread. From the created thread, I send a signal to main thread to get the current documentElement of the QWebView and main thread replies to to the thread and sets the local QWebElement variable in the thread. So, here is some code:

Thread has:

```
...
public slots:
   void setCurrentElement(QWebElement aElement);
signals:
   void sgGetCurrentElement(void);
private:
   QWebElement currentElement;
```

Main thread has:

```
...
public slots:
    void onGetCurrentElementReceived(void);
signals:
    void sgResponseToGetElement(QWebElement aElement);
```

After creating the thread, I connect the signals to slots like:

```
connect(insExtractor, SIGNAL(sgGetCurrentElement()), this, SLOT(onGetCurrentElementReceived()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(sgResponseToGetElement(QWebElement)), insExtractor, SLOT(setCurrentElement(QWebElement)));
```

Once the main thread receives a signal from the thread, it does the following:

```
void targetClass::onGetCurrentElementReceived(void)
{
     emit sgResponseToGetElement(insWebView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement());
}
```

The setter in the thread does the following:

```
void createdThread::setCurrentElement(QWebElement aElement)
{
     currentElement = aElement;
}
```

Here is the problem:
My target is to find the first form element whose id is submitForm. There is such a form in the element, no problem there.
If I write the following line before emitting the signal in the main thread:
    QWebElement form_found = currentElement.findFirst("form[id='submitForm']");

form_found  doesn't return null and it finds the form element. No problem.
If I write the same code right after I set the currentElement in setCurrentElement in the thread, it does the same and it finds the form. However, if I do the same right after I emit the very first signal again in the thread, it returns null. Here is the code:

```
void createdThread::startExtracting(void)
{
     sgGetCurrentElement();
     QThread::msleep(2000);
     QWebElement form_found = currentElement.findFirst("form[id='submitForm']");
}
```

So, form_found is coming null. Could anyone tell me why it is returning null? I put logs everywhere and it is being called after it is set in the setter. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Show a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem. It's not clear what is connected to what. I see current element set in target2dehandsExtractor class, and then targetThread trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspect is that you are stopping the event loop of the thread doing the sleep.

Threads in Qt are a bit tricky. Take a look at [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects), it makes all these questions very clear.

I'd say you should use the `Element` when you are sure you got it and that's on `setCurrentElement`. Why don't you start the extraction on that method ?

Comment: Please have a look at my simplified example code. I will enter to a new era after knowing what is wrong with the code. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6g5eu6okytsukf/problem.zip

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a webkit Qt built and can't compile your code. Anyway, i think it would be better if you edit your post providing the details.